# Boilerplate.js Programmatically navigate to a component

Tags: boilerplatejs

I have a component declared in a module and added as a route:

var controller = new Boiler.UrlController($(".appcontent"));
        controller.addRoutes( {
            'artists': new ArtistsComponent(context),
            'clubs': new ClubsComponent(context)
        });
        controller.start();

I need to navigate to a component like 'clubs' programmatically.  What is the exact syntax, please

Answer (score 0):

You may see how this is done to navigate from list view to details view in the sample code in:

https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs/blob/master/src/modules/sampleModule2/employeeList/viewmodel.js

The method call to navigate programmatically is:

```
Boiler.UrlController.goTo("artists");
```